# Getting reserved timeslot with ALM or Performance Center REST API

Tags: api, loadrunner, alm, microfocus, hp-performance-center

How can we get the list of the scheduled performances tests in ALM or Performance Center ? are these informations available from the REST API ?
I have to develop a java application which will get these different timeslot and and add some other timeslots scheduled by other tools to aggregate and display them in a dashboard.

I'm on ALM 12.53.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access to timeslots through REST API is not currently supported (my version is 12.55); You will have to deal with http requests.